# How do I pass an object to a directive?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm having issues getting an object to pass to my directive.  I believe I've done things correctly, but after failed attempt after failed attempt I must seek help.  What did I miss here that's stopping me from passing an array to my directive?

HTML:

```
<div class="body">
   {{orderList.length}} //shows up as 18
</div>
<queue-summary orders="orderList"></queue-summary>
```

Javascript:

```
directive('queueSummary', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            orders: '='
        },
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/partials/admin/bits/queue-summary.htm',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(scope, element, attrs); //$attrs.orders show it as the String "orderList" instead of the array
        }
    }
}).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attrs` will just show you the string value of an attribute.  In order to access the passed object, use the isolate binding you created:

```
console.log(scope.orders);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that you can access the bound value of an attribute you don't have isolate scope on with $eval:

```
scope.$eval(attrs.orders)
```